# How to build and deploy a multiple module Spring Boot maven app on External Tomcat container with Jenkins

Tags: spring-boot, jenkins, tomcat, tomcat8, multi-module

My Spring boot app is a multi-module app and have 3 modules

1. models
2. service-impl
3. service-api

Each module has it own `pom.xml` with packaging type `jar`.

Parent `pom.xml` have packaging type `pom`

I am able to build and deploy it to integrated server on my local system but not sure how to build and deploy it via Jenkins Job on external tomcat server.
Is it possible to deploy them together in single war package or I have to build and deploy each service separately.